# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: static

I want to pass myConnString in all forms. ( I am working in winform and mysql C#. ) So I tried [this link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/49952).

```
   static class GlobalClass
    {
        private string myConnString = "";

        public static string GlobalVar
        {
            get { return myConnString; }
            set { myConnString = value }
        }
    }
```

The above code gives the error :-

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

What is the mistake?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your myConnString field should be static too :)